# Is it possible to create an lwc that other lwcs can be drag and dropped into?

Tags: lightning-web-components, visual-workflow, slots

I would like to create an LWC (lets call it the Parent LWC) that is usable within the Flow builder. When Parent LWC is dragged onto a Flow screen, I'd like for the user to be able to drag other Flow accessible LWCs into designated slots on the Parent LWC.

Is this currently possible using slots or other LWC features?

Ive seen it described for Experience Builder but nothing that shows whether this is possible in Screen Flows. Any pointers would be most appreciated.

Comment: I don't believe the flow, page and experience builders have any mechanism for this. Where did you see about flow builder? Are you confusing this with property inputs?

Comment: I saw salesforce article about how to do this in experience builder. Flow is what Im hoping to confirm. Not confusing with properties - I would like to be able to drop lwcs into lwc slots in flow screen builder

Comment: Can you provide a link to the article please?

Comment: I'm assuming you mean a [Custom Theme Layout](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.246.0.communities_dev.meta/communities_dev/components_config_for_builder_layouts.htm) when you are talking about the Experience Cloud example? The only way in which I think this *might* be possible in Flow would be to create a Custom Property Editor and look at using the new [dynamic instantiation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/platform/lwc/guide/js-dynamic-components.html) capabilities. It's not quite the same, but could get you close enough to what you're after.

Comment: Cheers Callum will review and update this thread with result